# Handling JSON+ Stack Traces using logstash+ FileBeat

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration, elastic-stack

I'm trying to parse some JSON log files(that have stackTraces within them) into Logstash, but I think the stack traces are not letting it happen.

here is my logstash conf: (one of the many confs I've tried  )

```
input {
# This configuration works but the input file needs to be set in a format like so [{},{}] 
    file {
        path => "/opt/logstash/confFiles/suite1.json"
        start_position => beginning
        codec  => json
        sincedb_path => "/opt/logstash/confFiles/suite1incedb"
    }

} 

filter {
    json{
        source => "message"
    }
}

output {
    stdout {codec => rubydebug}
}
```

This is the json TYPE I'm trying to work around (its the result of a jsonReporter for jasmine)

```
{
    "suite1": {
        "id": "suite1",
        "description": "create process - simulate test 2",
        "fullName": "create process - simulate test 2",
        "failedExpectations": [],
        "status": "finished",
        "specs": [{
            "id": "spec0",
            "description": "should redirect to modeler after create a process",
            "fullName": "create process - simulate test 2 should redirect to modeler after create a process",
            "failedExpectations": [{
                "matcherName": "toMatch",
                "message": "Expected 'http://localhost:3000/#!/signin' to match /myDashboard/.",
                "stack": "Error: Failed expectation\n    at Env.<anonymous> (/home/ls/code/ph/app/tests/e2e/create-process.e2e.test.js:18:35)\n    at /home/ls/code/ph/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:95:14\n    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/home/ls/code/ph/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1654:20)\n    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (/home/ls/code/ph/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1518:8)\n    at [object Object].wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:274:14)\n    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:119:15)",
                "passed": false,
                "expected": {},
                "actual": "http://localhost:3000/#!/signin"
            }, {
                "matcherName": "",
                "message": "Failed: No element found using locator: By.id(\"selectedUser\")",
                "stack": "Error: Failed: No element found using locator: By.id(\"selectedUser\")\n    at stack (/home/ls/code/ph/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1441:17)\n    at buildExpectationResult (/home/ls/code/ph/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1411:14)\n    at Spec.Env.expectationResultFactory (/home/ls/code/ph/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:533:18)\n    at Spec.addExpectationResult (/home/ls/code/ph/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:293:34)\n    at Env.fail (/home/ls/code/ph/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:837:25)\n    at Function.next.fail (/home/ls/code/ph/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1776:19)\n    at /home/ls/code/ph/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:104:16\n    at /home/ls/code/ph/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15\n    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/home/ls/code/ph/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1654:20)\n    at notify (/home/ls/code/ph/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:465:12)",
                "passed": false,
                "expected": "",
                "actual": ""
            }],
            "passedExpectations": [],
            "status": "failed"
        }]
    },
    "suite2": {
        "id": "suite2",
        "description": "login to PB Modeler",
        "fullName": "login to PB Modeler",
        "failedExpectations": [],
        "status": "finished",
        "specs": [{
            "id": "spec1",
            "description": "should redirect to myDashboard after login",
            "fullName": "login to PB Modeler should redirect to myDashboard after login",
            "failedExpectations": [{
                "matcherName": "toMatch",
                "message": "Expected 'http://localhost:3000/#!/signin' to match /myDashboard/.",
                "stack": "Error: Failed expectation\n    at Env.<anonymous> (/home/ls/code/ph/app/tests/e2e/login.e2e.test.js:18:37)\n    at /home/ls/code/ph/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:95:14\n    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/home/ls/code/ph/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1654:20)\n    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (/home/ls/code/ph/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1518:8)\n    at [object Object].wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:274:14)\n    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:119:15)",
                "passed": false,
                "expected": {},
                "actual": "http://localhost:3000/#!/signin"
            }],
            "passedExpectations": [],
            "status": "failed"
        }]
    }
```

I've try many configurations now,
If I try to send it like it is above, Logstash will not map it correctly.
So what I did was remove the spaces and set beautify=false in the reporter and surrounded it with "[ ]" to make it look like an array and Logstash would "randomly" take it.

-So what would it be a good approach to parse both the nested JSON objects,taking into account the stackTraces, so that when its sent to ES and kibana is a workable DATA.

-How can I make a mapping for this structure or Model the data so that it understands it when sending this to ELK

I'm using
 ES 2.1
Logstash 2.1
Kibana 4.3.1
Filebeat 1.0.1

Comment: I'm not aware of the language of the application that is logging. But I've found https://github.com/dwbutler/logstash-logger (for Ruby) and https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder (for Java) to be really helpful. That will eliminate the need of parsing separately. I know this doesn't answer your question, but I hope it helps.